# How to inject the service in the NestJs+mongoose models

Tags: dependency-injection, nestjs

I want to inject the service that I have defined in the **client.audienceDetail.service.ts** into the customer schema

The client.audienceDetail.service.ts file code:

```
@Injectable()
export class AudienceDetailsService {
    constructor(@InjectModel(AudienceDetail.name) private audienceDetailsModel: Model<AudienceDetail>) {}

    async getAudienceIdByName(name: string) {
        const audienceId = await this.audienceDetailsModel.findOne<AudienceDetail>({ audienceName: name });
        return audienceId;
    }
}
```

The customer entity file:

```
@Schema({
    collection: DATABASE_COLLECTION.CUSTOMER,
    timestamps: true,
})
@ObjectType()
export class Customer extends Model<ICustomer> {
    @Prop()
    birthDate: Date;

    //... other properties
}

export const CustomerSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Customer);

CustomerSchema.post('insertMany', async function (docs) {
    try {
        // @ts-ignore
        for (const doc of docs) {
            const year = doc.birthDate.getFullYear();
            console.log({ year });
            let audienceId = null;

            if (year > 1996) {
                audienceId = await this.audienceDetailsService.getAudienceIdByName('genZ'); //I Want to use here
            }

            console.log({ audienceId });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
});
```

I have tried injecting the service in the Customer class like this:

```
constructor(@Inject(AudienceDetailsService) private audienceDetailsService: AudienceDetailsService) {
    super();
}
```

but it won't work as I am using the audienceDetailsService in the CustomerSchema and not the customer class.